# Using Magento API to add all products to root category

Tags: magento

I want to set **all** the products to the root category (next to the current category they are in).

I know the best way to do this is using the Magento API, but can somebody get me started on this?

Just to be clear, i **don't** want to change the category id, i just want to add another category id to the product.

EDIT

It takes a lot time to check all 3000+ products to see in what other category it is. Example: Root_catId = 175 Product_1 cat = 3 (needs to be: 3, 175) Product_2 cat = 9 (needs to be: 9, 175)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using the API but if you want to use the API try following.

You can use following first you need to create a user with permissions to access soap requests in Magento admin

```
<?php

$proxy = new SoapClient('http://yourmagento/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); 
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey'); 

$result = $proxy->catalogCategoryAssignProduct($sessionId, '3', '10'); // 3 is category id and 10 is product id
```

You can loop through every product to assign the product to a specific category.
Replace the root category id with the category id which you require.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Muk, what other way is there to change it, not using SQL right?

Beside that, it takes to much time to check all 3000 products to see in what other category it is. 

Example:

Root_catId = 175

Product_1 cat = 3 (needs to be: 3, 175)
Product_2 cat = 9 (needs to be: 9, 175) 

Sorry for the miscommunication.